# 'mv' equivalent of drag and drop with replace?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

In a GUI environment, a drag-and-drop with replace will replace files and entire directories (including contents) with whatever is being copied in. Is there a way to accomplish this same intuitive result with the 'mv' command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not with `mv`.

The core function of `mv` (despite its name) is to *rename* an object.  One of the guarantees that UNIX makes is that renames are atomic -- you're never allowed to see a partially completed rename.  This guarantee can be very useful if you want to change a file (`/etc/passwd`, for example) that other programs may be looking at, and you want them to see either the old or new version of the file, *and no other possibility*.  But a "recursive rename" like you describe would break that guarantee -- you could stop it in the middle and you'd have a half-moved tree and probably a mess -- and so it doesn't really fit in with the philosophy of `mv`.  That's my guess as to why `mv -r` doesn't exist.

(Never mind that `mv` breaks that philosophy in other, smaller ways.  For example, `mv` actually does a `cp` followed by `rm` when moving files from one filesystem to another.)

Enough philosophy.  If you want to recursively move ("drag-drop") a tree from one place to another *on the same filesystem*, you can get the efficiency and speed of `mv` as follows (for example):

```
cp -al source/* dest/ && rm -r source/*
```

The `-l` flag to `cp` means "create a hard link instead of copying" -- it's effectively creating a new filename that points to the same file data as the old filename.  This only works on filesystems that support hard links, though -- so any native UNIX-ish filesystem is fine, but it won't work with FAT.

The `&&` means "only run the following command if the preceding command succeeded".  If you like, you can run the two commands one at a time instead.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can replicate the drag-drop behavior you're describing with `mv`, as non-empty subdirectories in the target won't be replaced.

Perhaps `rsync`?  Something like `rsync -a -r source/ target/`?  Run with the `-v -n` to do a verbose dry-run first to make sure it does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`mv -f /path/to/source/folder/* /destination/folder/`

Will move everything in /path/to/source/folder, including files and directories to /destination/folder.

And will overwrite existing files and directories.

Comment: Only empty directories

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to change the correct answer to this:

https://github.com/iaindooley/pickdrop

Example:

say I have:

```
test/
test/index.php
test/images/
test/images/a.jpg
test/images/thing.png
```

and I want to move these things to /site

so it looks like:

```
site/
site/public/
site/public/index.php
site/public/a.jpg
site/public/thing.png
```

I can go:

```
cd images &&
pick a.jpg thing.png
cd .. &&
pick index.php &&
cd .. &&
mkdir site &&
mkdir site/public &&
cd site/public &&
drop
```

This is literally cut & paste.

Comment: Very cool, and definitely worth looking into. However, the question was specifically about 'mv' so I think I'll leave the correct answer as the one that explains the philosophy behind mv in detail. Thank you for this contribution though, definitely very helpful.

Comment: Also notable, from the readme: "It's not robust at all - it stores your picks
in ~/.pick until you call drop at which time it
uses the file paths in ~/.pick to create a new
executable ~/.drop file to copy each of the
files you picked to the current working
directory."